# R: For loop appending dataframe to existing list of dataframes only returns first value

Tags: r, for-loop, append

Got a list of dataframes with different numbers of rows.  I have a function that calculates the value for a new column, which works on its own (I will not go into detail it is evolution/phylogenetics and needlessly complicated).  I am trying to run this function to create a new column for each of 9000 dataframes in a list of dataframes, but the function only returns the first value.

I created an empty dataframe populated by "a" which I'd like it to be appended to.  I do not know what I am doing wrong...

```
all_shifts = function(df_list){
  empty_df = data.frame(col1= "a",col2= "a",col3= "a",col4= "a",col5= "a",col6= "a",col7= "a",col8= "a")
  for (i in 1:length(df_list)){
    df_list[[i]]$col8= function_1(df_list[[i]]$col1,df_list)
    empty_df = rbind(empty_df,df_list[[i]])
  }
}
```

Comment: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will try to use it.  But my issue is lower-level than that I fear...  I'm not sure I can even get it to loop over each dataframe in the list and run the function, let alone make a list of it to rbind

Comment: Perhaps if you provide a sample for `df_list` that we can play with, there's a better chance we can help. Please use `dput(.)` or programmatic formation (`list(data.frame(..), data.frame(..))` for a small, contained sample. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.